# MS Excel Extract all rows from a range based on conditions

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, row

i'm trying to extract all row from a range that meet my conditions, here is my table

| Group | first name & last name | N°invoice | invoice Date | Excl. Tax | VAT | Incl. TAX | O.B | Rest | date of payment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Someone 01 | 10001 | 2022/01/01 | 1000 | 50 | 1050 | paid | 0 | 2022/01/15 |
| B | Someone 02 | 10002 | 2022/01/01 | 1000 | 50 | 1050 | Partial Paid | 550 | 2022/01/14 |
| A | Someone 01 | 10003 | 2022/01/10 | 1500 | 75 | 1575 | Partial Paid | 75 | 2022/01/15 |
| C | Someone 03 | 10004 | 2022/01/10 | 1500 | 75 | 1575 | paid | 0 | 2022/01/15 |

I find in the internet a way to extract Rows of **N°invoice**  based on one condition **first name & last name** After clicking CTRL + SHIFT and then swap down the formula

`=INDEX($C$2:$C$04, SMALL(IF($B$10=$B$2:$B$04, ROW($B$2:$B$04)-ROW($C$2)+1), ROW(1:1)))`

B10 is the cell that contain the name that im looking for.

i want to add one more condition so that it well extract by a certain **first name & last name** and **Rest** is
**NOT equal** to 0

i try
`=INDEX($C$2:$C$04, SMALL(IF(AND($B$10=$B$2:$B$04,0<>$H$2:$N$145), ROW($B$2:$B$04)-ROW($C$2)+1), ROW(1:1)))`

but it only extract the first row in the index

Comment: What is your Excel Version? If you are a O365 user then use `FILTER()` Function and if not then use `INDEX()` with `AGGREGATE()` function, And have you searched in SO there are lot of examples on the same for multiple records extraction.

Comment: Its Office 2019 , How to use INDEX() with AGGREGATE() ?

Comment: Like this --> `=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$04,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$B$04)-ROW($C$2)+1)/(($B$10=$B$2:$B$04)*($H$2:$N$145<>"")),ROW(A1))),"")` and it doesn't require to press `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`

Comment: You can add your conditions as I did like this way, `(($B$10=$B$2:$B$04)*($H$2:$N$145<>""))` . Here `*` acts as an `AND` function while `+` will be for `OR`

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Try to switch on `O365` there is more magic & fun with `Excel`

Comment: @Mayukh you could also use actual row references (without substracting header row calculation) by indexing the whole column: `=IFERROR(INDEX($C:$C$,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$2:$B$145))/(($B$10=$B$2:$B$145)*($I$2:$I$145<>0)),ROW(A1))),"")` I also changed the range up to row 145 for all array ranges.